# how to convert Bitmap Image to jpeg2000

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, bmp, jpeg2000

There are images which are in Bitmap format i need to convert it to jpeg2000 form. can you please tel me steps included in this.how can images can be converted from bmp to jpeg2000. how can i do this thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you tried at least doing `bitmap.Save(@"C:\image.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Magick.NET (https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET).

```cs
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("input.bmp"))
{
  image.Write("output.jp2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jpeg2000.Net library](https://bitmiracle.com/jpeg2000/). Disclaimer: I am working on this library, the library is commercial.

Here are basic samples for encoding of BMP image to JPEG 2000:

a. Lossless encoding

```
J2kImageData imageData = J2kImageData.FromImage("input.bmp");
imageData.Encode("output-lossless.j2k");
```

b. Encoding with compression

```
J2kImageData imageData = J2kImageData.FromImage("input.bmp");

var options30x = new J2kEncodingOptions
{
    Codec = J2kCodec.J2k,
    QualityMode = J2kQualityMode.CompressionRatio,
    QualityValues = new float[] { 30 }
};
imageData.Encode(@"output-30x.j2k", options30x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly you would like to do it, however, you may want to look into ImageMagick features. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/jp2.php

Answer (score -2):

Use FileStream .

```
byte[] raw = File.ReadAllBytes("pic.bmp");

using(Image img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(raw)))
{
    img.Save("pic.jp2", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: I think panchi wants JPEG2000, the code you posted is saving the image as JPEG (1992).